# Using CNN on non-image 1-D data

Tags: neural-network, tf-slim

I have a 2-D matrix of dimensions (batch size x 1000). The values are not random and do have meaning in their structure - they are ordered by time.

I wanted to try and use a CNN on this data. Is it possible to run a CNN on non-image data such as this? I've been having trouble with it since tf-slim requires that the rank of the input be >= 3.

From what I understand, CNNs need an input rank of [batch size, height, width, channel]. How can I convert what I have into that form using tf.reshape()?

Comment: Usually, CNN is a tool to detect some feature locating in a picture, that's why there is a 3 dimensional layer of neurons (maybe you confused it with a 3 dimensional input?).
So what is the purpose of this CNN here?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sorry, I forgot to mention but the purpose here is to do classification based on the features - there are roughly ~4000 classes possible.